# custom growl message border color

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, growl

In growl messages, there is always a blue border, which I want to get rid of. Tried adding border-color to different growl classes but it still shows, I want a black border, what should I do? Below is my css, thanks.

```
.ui-growl{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin-top: -50px;
margin-left: -100px;
border-color: black}


.ui-growl-item{color:black;background-color:gray; border-color: black;}

.ui-growl-item-container {background-color:gray;border-color:black;  }
```

Comment: Please include the relevant markup.

Comment: hi kevin, sorry didn't get you.

Comment: We will need to see the HTML that goes with the problmatic styling

Comment: have replaced the color codes that were not properly showing in the post. thanks

Comment: Which theme are you using? It doesn't have a blue border on default Aristo theme.

Comment: now its working for me, the only class needed for the container border was .ui-growl-item-container and this css file was in my additionalstylesheet, which was being overwritten by some other css file, so changed the ordering of the stylesheets being applied to the page making additionalstylesheet the last one to be applied...

Comment: it's something called indium-stylesheet.css I found in the project and commenting it seemed to solve the issue, then found out this stylesheet was overriding my stylesheet. thanks BalusC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why it's blue in your case, perhaps you used a different theme than the default Aristo theme?

But anyway, the `<p:growl>` border is overrideable by the following selector:

```css
.ui-growl-item-container.ui-state-highlight {
    border-color: pink;
}
```

See also the following screenshot of the inspection using Chrome developer toolset:

[image]

Make sure that you specify the overridding style in a stylesheet which is included by a `<h:outputStylesheet>` in the `<h:body>` (instead of the `<h:head>`)

```
<h:head>
    ...
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:outputStylesheet name="custom.css" target="head" />
    ...
</h:body>
```

It will be relocated into the generated HTML `<head>` anyway and this approach guarantees that it's loaded *after* any of PrimeFaces-bundled stylesheets.